# Show that $u(x,y)=f(2y+x)+g(2y-x^2)$ is a general solution of the following equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Show that $u(x,y)=f(2y+x)+g(2y-x^2)$ is a general solution of the equation 
$$u_{xx}-1/xu_{x}-x^2u_{yy}=0$$

Finding $u_x, u_t, u_{yy}$ , we substitute them to the Pde and confirm equality, right?

or how to show it?

Comment: If you substitute the expression into the differential equation, you will show that the expression is **a** solution of the DE. You still ahve to prove that **all** solutions of the DE have tis form.

Comment: I understand thing you said, now. All right, How can we show it? Could you help me?

Comment: Judging by the proposed form of the solution, the method characteristics would be a good start. Otherwise, by the same reasoning, you might try to make a change of variables $s = 2y+x$, $t=2y-x^2$, find where this change of variables has sense, and then rewrite the differential equation it terms of derivatives with respect to $s$ and $t$.

Comment: how do we select $s$ and $t$? by looking function given $f$  ? or if it is not given?

Comment: by looking at the arguments of $f$ and $g$.